# How to create database tables upon joomla user creation

Tags: php, sql, joomla

Upon creating a user in joomla I would need the fields exported from one table to another. Any help in getting a simple structure of the query would really be appreciated.

```
#jml_users - #jmla_new_users
```

with the following fields, (username,firstname,lastname,email).

Also I have no clue where or how to insert it so if its not a completely different question I would appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've created a Joomla! User Plugin that should do what you need, simply install the plugin, enable it and enter the database table name in the params of where you would like the new user to 'copied to'.

You can download it at:

https://www.seanclement.co.uk/downloads/stackoverflow/duplicateuser/duplicate-user.zip

Things to note

1: Joomla doesn't separate/store the first name and last name - Joomla only stores 'name' and 'username' - the plugin will see if there is a 'space' within the name field and separate them out into 'firstname' and 'lastname'.

2: The fields for the database table are 'hard coded' in the plugin, they are 'username', 'email', 'firstname', 'lastname' - if they don't match the actual database table, there will be an error

3: The plugin is for Joomla 3.x

4: It doesn't affect users that are already in the system, only new users

When you have installed, enabled and added your database table name to the plugin, test it by adding a new user via the 'Users -> Manage -> Add new user'

Let me know if you have any issues.

Comment: Hey, i am getting some errors, i will try tomorrow to resolve it and get back to you. Thanks again i really really am greatful. I give you the green check anyway if at the end of this i cant resolve the problem

Comment: I keep getting this error- 

Save failed with the following error: Unknown column 'id' in 'field list' SQL=INSERT INTO `#__pin_user_settings` (`username`,`email`,`id`,`first_name`,`last_name`) VALUES ('Tessssssst','Tessssssst@aol.com','880','Tessssssst','Tessssssst')

Comment: It would appear that the '#__pin_user_settings' table doesn't have an 'id' column in it. If you login to your database via PHPMyAdmin and check the 'Structure' for that table - you will either see an 'id' field or you wont.

If you don't see 'id' - you will need to add it to the table, you can run the following SQL code which will add the 'id' field (you will want to replace the '#__' with your table prefix)

**ALTER TABLE `#__pin_user_settings` ADD `id` INT NOT NULL ;**

Comment: oops yea it was user_id :D :D :D :D YOUR TOO COOOOL!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! OH MY GOODNESS :D :D :D :D :D